# Total Energy of point charges and that of charged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, dielectric

I have a very basic question which I can't figure out.
Consider a point charge. Now, If we wish to calculate the total energy in this point charge system (using energy Density in field) it will come out to be infinite, but for a charged spherical shell or charged spherical volume, it comes out to be a finite value. This is not upto the expectations which I had, it comes natural that a combination of charges in sphere must possess infinite energy if a point charge have infinite energy in itself.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Consider the sphere of charge, and then move all the charges together to the point. The force required will go up and up, becoming infinite as you achieve a point charge. Bingo: infinite potential energy.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times it is possible that intuition gets encountered by Mathematics.Please carefully read the following definition of potential energy:-

> The change in potential energy of a system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system

Now this definition says that it is really essential that minimum of two particles are required for potential energy of a system to be defined.So saying that potential energy of a point charge is infinite is inconsistent with the above definition.

You can say that the potential energy of two point charge(like charges)system placed infinitesimaly close to each other tends to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

In reality there is no such a thing as a "point charge": if we "zoom in" enough, we will always see a point charge as a charge $q$ spread over a certain (spherical, radius $R$) volume $V$. Now, if we make the assumption (for the sake of simplicity) that the density charge $\rho = q / V$ is constant over $V$, by applying Gauss' law we find that the electric field is given by the usual Coulomb's law for $r > R$, whereas it is

$$
E(r) = \frac{\rho r}{3 \epsilon_0}
$$

for $r < R$. As you see, $\lim_{r \to 0} E(r) = 0$, which is much more sensible than the divergence you obtain by using Coulomb's law. Moreover, the energy associated to such a field does not diverge any more.

Comment: We define a point charge to be dimension less so how can you say that we must zoom in and find out that it is a sphere.

Comment: @Unique my point is that a point charge does not exist. Therefore, using point charges will lead to issues (such as diverging quantities such as the electric field or the energy)

Comment: Quantum Mechanically, I'm not sure if it makes sense to say something is smaller than its Compton Wavelength, $h/m_ec$ for an electron, iirc.